# Keycloak: HSM Provider for Realm Keys

Tags: keycloak, hardware-security-module

I'm looking for possibilities to have a *Keycloak* realm key be stored in an HSM and be loaded into memory on startup.

At the moment I can see the standard realm keys which are stored "unprotected" in the Keycloak integrated database. I have also found this discussion from 2016 [1] that suggests to implement encryption/signature SPIs to make encrypting/signing happen inside an HSM. This was also implemented as far as I see it [2].

However for the case of a login with signed access token this would require communication with the HSM every time a token is issued, which would - for a greater number of applications and users - cause serious impact on the duration of a login procedure.

If we want to circumvent this we could have a startup procedure that loads the realm keys from the HSM on startup and then keeps them in memory. But I could not find anything about such a feature being present or event considered. Is there any feature in this direction?

[1] https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-dev/2016-February/006610.html

[2] e.g. https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.1/javadocs/org/keycloak/crypto/SignatureSpi.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to delegate encryption/signing to HSM itself, then indeed, as you've noted yourself, this adds an overhead and may not always be feasible.

To avoid this, it's possible to load keys from HSM the first time Keycloak tries to use it and keep it in-memory for future logins. For this you can utilize Keycloak's [key SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.5/javadocs/org/keycloak/keys/KeySpi.html) by implementing [key provider](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.5/javadocs/org/keycloak/keys/KeyProvider.html). Then if you add it to your realm in the Keycloak Admin UI (**Realm settings -> Keys -> Providers tab**), Keycloak will call `KeyProvider#getKeysStream` whenever the key might be required. At this point you can load the key from wherever and perform any caching and key rotation strategy you need.

The custom key provider would look like this:

```
import org.keycloak.component.ComponentModel;
import org.keycloak.crypto.KeyWrapper;
import org.keycloak.keys.KeyProvider;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class HsmKeyProvider implements KeyProvider {

    private static final String NOTE_KEYS = "hsm-keys";
    private Collection<KeyWrapper> keys;

    public HsmKeyProvider(ComponentModel model) {
        if (model.hasNote(NOTE_KEYS)) {
            keys = model.getNote(NOTE_KEYS);
        } else {
            keys = loadKeys();
            model.setNote(NOTE_KEYS, keys);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<KeyWrapper> getKeysStream() {
        return keys.stream();
    }

    protected Collection<KeyWrapper> loadKeys() {
        // TODO: Load keys from HSM, wrap into KeyWrapper
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Provider factory:

```
import org.keycloak.component.ComponentModel;
import org.keycloak.keys.KeyProviderFactory;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession;
import org.keycloak.provider.ProviderConfigProperty;

import java.util.List;

public class HsmKeyProviderFactory implements KeyProviderFactory<HsmKeyProvider> {

    @Override
    public HsmKeyProvider create(KeycloakSession session, ComponentModel model) {
        return new HsmKeyProvider(model);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHelpText() {
        return "HSM key";
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties() {
        // TODO: You may want to have some dynamic configuration
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return "my-hsm-key-example";
    }
}
```

For details on how to develop and deploy custom providers to Keycloak, see the Keycloak's [Server Developer Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html) documentation page.